# d3 ordinal scale that adjusts to cluster size

Tags: d3.js

How can I shift the start point of each nested group according to how much space that group requires in each cluster to mainatin a constant bar width?   The ordinal scale allocates the same space for each cluster and then decreases the bar width to accomodate more bars but I want to adjust in a linear fashion to maintain the bar size.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what you're actually doing. It sounds like you would need to adjust the output range of your scale depending on the number of bars.

Comment: Can it be reset for each cluster?  I'm trying to create a grouped bar chart like this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 but with a variable number of bars in each group with the same bar width.

Comment: Well you would need to store the information on how much each group needs to be offset somewhere, either with the data or in a global variable.

Comment: I can get that from the number of bars in each group * bar width.  What is the best method to implement the offset?

Comment: Like I said, either make it part of the data or keep track of the current offset in a global variable.

Comment: I'm new to d3.  Do I change the domain to manage the offset or transform/translate or the .attr ("x", )?

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

Comment: In the example that you've linked to, every group is inside a `g` element with a translation. This is what you need to adjust.

Comment: I'm getting there.  How do I factor the global variable into this statement?
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

Comment: Well something like `+ offset`, where offset is computed from the width of the previous groups.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Have you tried swapping the 'ordinal' with 'linear'.. because you can specify multiple domain and range values just like in ordinal scales and d3 will use all of them like an ordinal scale, but keeps the smooth linear interpolation..  Check out how this behaves.</s>

<s>var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,2,3,4]).range([1,20,300,4000])</s>

---

Ok so after gaining more insight, it looks like you do have to copy the original scale and alter it to make a new scale for each object that has a different... umm, *scale*. Funny that obvious clue never entered my mind till just now.

I copied that d3 example into jsfiddle and altered it a little and seems to work. Was this the effect you were going for?

http://jsfiddle.net/2ktVC/2/

I mostly just replaced the harmless forEach loop in the example with these here guns.

```
data.forEach(function(d,i){/*-=======================*/
  var myNames = d3.keys(d).filter(function(key) { ////
  if(key !== "State" && d[key]){ /*-==============-*/
    allAgeNames[key]
        = true;
    return true;
  } return false;

  //==========
  xScales[i] = d3.scale.ordinal();/*==========*/
  d.ages = myNames.reduce(function(arr, name) {
    if(+d[name]) arr.push({
    value:+d[name],
     x:xScales[i],
      name: name
    });/*===*/
     return arr;
   },[]);/*

 //||||||||||||||||||||||||||==========================----*/
 xScales[i].domain(myNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x.rangeBand()], 0);
    d.x = /*|_|_|_|_|_*/
   xScales[i];
  d.ages.x =
 xScales[i]
});
```

Im kidding, stack overflow wont let me link to jsfiddle without some reference code.... so out come the jokes.

Comment: Can this be done dynamically if the dataset is changed?

Comment: I think so.. i mean, d3 scales are really versatile, You can give it a new domain and/or range at any time. In fact, most if not all scale methods can be called at any time, They all just tweak some configuration variable and call the same internal 'rescale' function that returns the same scale with new configuration.

Comment: But as somebody else commented, it's difficult to give a good answer with limited information in the question. Maybe you can include an example.

Comment: For example add a new state xxx and value for CA only to data.csv  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051.  I want to eliminate the blank space between the groups when there is no data present for a particular state.

Comment: AAhh! Ok, that's different.. You don't want missing teeth huh? It looks like you're best bet is probably  going to be to clone the scale (`x1` in the d3 example) probably at the same time as that initial `data.forEach`, and assign one to each group. And since x0 is only acting on one set (the states), it should be able to scale to the correct size when the data is changed and domain/range are updated, no other sets are depending on it. You may need to remove the value from the domain and range sets (for a single scale) to keep color consistency.

Comment: I like the analogy it's spot on but I need a little more help with the solution!  
Are you suggesting that I add an additional column of data with the offset already calculated?  
Or is there some way to adjust this on the fly based on the count of actual values for each state? 
Then modify x1 like this x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand() - adjustment], 0);

Comment: Brilliant.  Thanks for taking the time to work on this and create a fiddle.   Last remaining but critical task is to make all the bar widths equal in size.  I struggled with this in my earlier attempts because the ordinal scale adjusts the bar width to fill a fixed available space. Any ideas?

Comment: forgot to mention the tricky bit -no missing teeth when bars are equi- sized!

Comment: That gets a little more complex because of the groups.. The scale that  enforces the group width would need to change.. The ordinal scale will divide the ranges evenly so all groups are an equal width. You would need to come up with another way to distribute the widths based on the number of total bars in the chart.

If all groups are the same width and some groups have a different number of bars than others, then it is impossible to make all bars the same width... A different d3 scale type might do the trick, but I haven't used them much, so can't give advice in that area. sorry.

Comment: I can work out the width that is allocated to each group by the ordinal scale and I can also work out the proportion that is actually required based on the number of bars in the group.  
A suggestion from Lars above was to pass this into a global variable and then implement an offset on the domain -I think.  Any thoughts on how this might be applied to your solution?

Comment: Minor update to fix bar width but still has too much white space! http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/T3qHk/1/

Comment: I've changed the data format and need help to get this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/tsLCD/2/ looking like http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/T3qHk/1/